# Data revert in my Android app

Tags: android, appdata

I have released an app on Google Play made with Construct 2, and I have a big problem.

One of the users of my app have complained on losing data, but not entirely. For example, he was on level 27 and had 240 coins, and somehow he was sent back to level 12 with less coins. It has nothing to do with the code, and it happened only to him and me.

How come the value for the level, coins and all progress is reverted to some value that was stored before?

I am also having a problem with huge data size. The data of my app is 40MB, and I am only saving a 2260 long value as JSON..

Is it possible that my data is accumulating every time it saves? For example, the values for levels are not replaced but saved as new instead of only saving the highest level, so in the data there are multiple level values (1,2,3,4....20) and they sometimes conflict and load a wrong (lower level) value.

This would explain the huge data size, but what may cause it?

Comment: How do you save this data?

Comment: There is a LocalStorage plugin in Construct 2 which allows you to save data on the device and load it. But when running my app in debug mode, I can see that it only saves the data I order it to (the 2260 long string), and nothing more than that. I've also made a debug message and opened my app on mobile but I get the same result.